# Understanding why MongoDB skips certain documents during a find() operation on entire collection

Tags: mongodb

So, we use MongoDB at our workplace to store certain information about our customers in a collection named `customers`. For an ad-hoc task, I am required to iterate through the entire collection and do some processing on each document, which means that it is critical to scan through every document in the collection without missing any.

This is the query I am running -

`db.customers.find({}, {"cid":1, "name":1})`

The `customers` collection has an index on the `cid` field, and this is the result of execution-stats on the query -

```
"executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "PROJECTION",
            "nReturned" : 19841,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 10,
            "works" : 19843,
            "advanced" : 19841,
            "needTime" : 1,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 155,
            "restoreState" : 155,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "transformBy" : {
                "cid" : 1,
                "name":1
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                "nReturned" : 19841,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "works" : 19843,
                "advanced" : 19841,
                "needTime" : 1,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 155,
                "restoreState" : 155,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "docsExamined" : 19841
            }
        }
```

The issue I am facing is that when I run this query, MongoDB doesn't include a few `cid`s in the cursor, which should ideally be present. Those `cid`s where part of the collection before the query started running. When I run the same query again at a later date, it so happens that these documents are returned, but some other documents go missing.

From what I got from reading up before asking this question, it looks like [Reads may miss matching documents that are updated during the course of the read operation in MongoDB](https://blog.meteor.com/mongodb-queries-dont-always-return-all-matching-documents-654b6594a827). The article seems to hint that this, however, happens only when the query uses an index and not during an entire collection scan, which is what I am doing. My query doesn't seem to use any index so I expect to not run into this issue. However, this does happen in my case as well.

So, two questions:

1. Is my understanding of the issue correct?
2. How to resolve this problem and retrieve all the existing documents in the `customers` collection without missing any of them?

Thanks

Comment: What u got when u execute `db.customers.find({});`

Comment: @MarcelDjaman I got the results as was expected, just that many of them were missing which I discovered the next time I ran the query.

Comment: Does all your document has a name field ?

Comment: Can you try `db.customers.find({}, {"cid":1, "name":1}).snapshot()`?

Comment: @JohnnyHK I can try, but since it's our production system, would like to understand from you why it could possibly solve the problem.

Documentation says - ```The $snapshot operator prevents the cursor from returning a document more than once because an intervening write operation results in a move of the document.```, which is not an issue for us. Kindly comment why you feel it would solve the problem we are facing.

Comment: You're looking for a consistent set of all documents from the collection, which should be what a cursor snapshot provides. Docs are pretty thin on the topic, and only describe it in terms of preventing duplicates, but logically it should address your case as well. Are you using the MMAPv1 or WiredTiger storage engine?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/#what-isolation-guarantees-does-mongodb-provide doesn't say anything about indexes. It's just *3. Reads may miss matching documents that are updated during the course of the read operation.*

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you running?  We ran into an issue where we had inconsistent reads with versions between 3.0.0 and <3.0.8.  It was fixed post 3.0.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The article you reference mentions that if scanning over the whole collection, writes may change a document and cause a re-order of the documents of the collection if a document grows and needs to be moved. The author's solution is to use an index that will ensure no documents are missed in the cursor iteration. Thus, ["natural order"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#return-natural-order) can be volatile during iteration.
2. I suggest using a stable index for the scan. In your case,

   `db.customers.find({}, {"cid":1, "name":1}).hint({cid: 1})`

   will result in an index scan being the query planner's winning plan (Confirm with `db.customers.find({}, {"cid":1, "name":1}).hint({cid: 1}).explain()`).